# __FILE__ macro shows full path

Tags: c, file, path, macros, preprocessor

The standard predefined macro `__FILE__` available in C shows the full path to the file. Is there any way to shorten the path and get just the filename? I mean instead of

```
/full/path/to/file.c
```

I see

```
to/file.c
```

or

```
file.c
```

Comment: It would be really really great to find a preprocessor-only solution. I'm afraid that the suggestions based on string operations will execute at runtime.

Comment: Since you're using gcc, I think you can change what `__FILE__` contains by changing the filename you pass on the command line. So instead of `gcc /full/path/to/file.c`, try `cd /full/path/to; gcc file.c; cd -;`. Of course there's a bit more to it than that if you're relying on gcc's current directory for the include path or output file location. Edit: the gcc docs suggest that it's the full path, *not* the input file name argument, but that's not what I'm seeing for gcc 4.5.3 on Cygwin. So you may as well try it on Linux and see.

Comment: GCC 4.5.1 (built for arm-none-eabi specifically) uses the exact text of the file name on its command line. In my case it was the IDE's fault for invoking GCC with all file names fully qualified instead of putting the current directory somewhere sensible (location of the project file, perhaps?) or configurable and using relative paths from there. I suspect a lot of IDEs do that (especially on Windows) out of some sort of discomfort related to explaining where the "current" directory really is for a GUI app.

Comment: @SteveJessop - hope you read this comment. I have a situation where I see `__FILE__` printed as `../../../../../../../../rtems/c/src/lib/libbsp/sparc/leon2/../../shared/bootcard.c` and I want to know where gcc compiled the file such that this file is relatively located like it is shown.

Comment: This question is not a dupe of the linked one. For one, the linked one is about C++, and the answers consequently delves into C++ macro esoterica. Second, there is nothing in OP's question which mandates a macro solution. It only solemnly points out a problem and asks an open ended question.

Comment: I know this ask is years old, but this will be possible to do at compile time [in GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=256847) (I don't *think* that made it onto the 8 branch, but I could be wrong).

Comment: You could use the `basename()` function to extract just the current file name for printing

Comment: With at least the `C++11` you can do it at compile time instead of in the preprocessor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path/54335644#54335644

Comment: FYI here is a 4 line `c++11` solution using compile-time `constexpr` tested with g++ version 4.8.5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237385/52074

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Try

```
#include <string.h>

#define __FILENAME__ (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__)
```

For Windows use '\\' instead of '/'.

Comment: @mahmood: `strrchr` returns a pointer to the `/` (or a null pointer if it doesn't find a `/`), so `+1` means that the resulting pointer is one character further on. Without it, the result string would be `/file.c` instead of `file.c`.

Comment: `/` is a valid path separator in Windows.

Comment: But I think all of path has to be with forward slashes.

Comment: `/` is a valid path separator in file names passed to CreateFile() and so forth. However, that doesn't always mean that you can use `/` just anywhere in Windows since there is a tradition (inherited from CPM) of using `/` as the argument lead in at the command prompt. But a quality tool would be careful to split file names at *both* slash and backslash characters to avoid any problems for folks that do manage to use `/`.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, no you can mix both separators in the same file name.

Comment: `__FILE__` may contain mixed separators, in my case I see `c:\phpdesktop\phpdesktop-src\phpdesktop-msie\msie/internet_features.h`. Anyone have a macro for that?

Comment: If your platform supports it `char* fileName = basename(__FILE__);`  It's definitely there in Linux and OS X, don't know about Windows though.

Comment: I tried that with '\\' for windows and it didn't work , can you please help me see what I am missing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493937/base-file-name-from-file

Comment: This does work indeed, but unfortunately you'll still find the full path in the executable.

Comment: This could be shortened to `strrchr("/" __FILE__, '/') + 1`.  By prepending "/" to `__FILE__`, strrchr is be guaranteed to find something, and thus the conditional ?: is no longer needed.

Comment: Also works great if you use `strstr(__FILE__, "my_source_directory")`. With that you can keep the paths within the project.

Comment: `char* fileName = basename(__FILE__);` is dangerous.  `basename()` can modify its argument string.  Per [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html): *The `basename()` function may modify the string pointed to by `path`* That could result in a SEGV if the string `__FILE__` expands to is read-only.  Also see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html

Comment: You can easily avoid a second call to strrchr with a local variable:
`#define __FILENAME__ ({const char * pStr = strrchr(__FILE__, '/'); pStr ? pStr + 1 : __FILE__;})`

Comment: For those who interested both *strrchr* and *strstr* work in compile time in this case, tested with gcc 6.3.0 -O2.

Comment: @AndrewSelivanov how did you verify that this is done at compile time?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith built with --save-temps and inspected generated code

Comment: A detail: the "__" pre- and postfix is a notation reserved to the implementation.

Comment: @mrtumnus - I get the (pedantic) warning: "ISO C++ forbids braced-groups within expressions", pointing to the first parenthesis.

Comment: @Pietro Yeah, the extra parens probably aren't necessary.  They carried over from the OP's original statement.

Comment: I wonder if the optimizer is able to optimize the calls to `strchr` and `strrchr`. Not to mention references to the `__FILENAME__` macro. If not, this solution is 100% bloat.

Comment: This does not optimize out the strrchr in the latest MSVC v19.

Comment: Not a solution for realtime applications. I used Simon Watts solution below and it does much the same without all the string processing.

Answer (score 61):

Here's a tip if you're using cmake.  From:
http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2013-January/053117.html

I'm copying the tip so it's all on this page:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D__FILENAME__='\"$(subst
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/,,$(abspath $<))\"'")
```

If you're using GNU make, I see no reason you couldn't extend this to your own makefiles.  For example, you might have a line like this:

```
CXX_FLAGS+=-D__FILENAME__='\"$(subst $(SOURCE_PREFIX)/,,$(abspath $<))\"'"
```

where `$(SOURCE_PREFIX)` is the prefix that you want to remove.

Then use `__FILENAME__` in place of `__FILE__`.

Comment: This is a great idea! Much better than pulling in the standard string library to trim the filename, which isn't really an option on most embedded platforms.

Comment: I am afraid then this doesn't work for the __FILE__ referenced in header file.

Comment: Agree with @BaiyanHuang but not sure that the comment is clear.  `__FILE__` is not a simple preprocessor symbol, it changes to the current file is often used for emitting the name of the current file (header or source module).  This `__FILENAME__` would only have the outermost source

Comment: How would you remove the file extension with this? Keeping only basename?

Comment: @Kernald Try using `$(basename $(abspath $<))` instead of `$(abspath $<)`

Comment: Well, that was… unexpectedly simple! Thanks. It works like a charm.

Comment: Great idea! That solved my file path too long in log file problem.

Comment: This answer's solution is not portable since it uses Bourne shell escapes.  Better to use CMake to implement it in a clean and portable way.  See [define_file_basename_for_sources macro answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27990434/994153) here.

Comment: @thegreendroid: there is nothing wrong with using 'strrchr' even on an embedded platform as this function just seeks memory and pretty fast. Furthermore, it's also a part of of both C89 and C99.

Comment: The GNU Make variant of this is
    CFLAGS += -D__FILENAME__=\"$(notdir $<)\"

Comment: @firegurafiku  On embedded platforms, code size is often more of a constraint than speed. If you have debug statements in each file, that can quickly balloon file-size up with full-path strings. I'm dealing with such a platform at the moment, and referencing `__FILE__` everywhere is blowing out of code-space.

Comment: Don't work with cmake + ninja:
ninja: error: build.ninja:221: bad $-escape (literal $ must be written as $$)

Comment: ⚠️when you follow this method, you break Visual Studio's (as of 2019) /MP parallel compilation. As it batches compilation and having per-file compiling options degrades to batches of size 1. See https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/make-vc-compiles-fast-through-parallel-compilation/

Comment: I got "Using `$<` in a non-suffix rule context is a GNUmake idiom" from a non-GNU make. I used `$(notdir $file)` instead.

Comment: In addition to working only with the make generator, this will no longer work starting with CMake 3.20. An alternative that is still make-specific is: `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D__FILENAME__='\"$(notdir $(abspath $@))\"'")`

Comment: I can confirm this answer does not work and broke my cmakelists, I got `c++: fatal error: no input files`. I can also confirm that the above linked helper from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27990434/994153) works great. Thanks @ColinDBennett

Comment: Works, but leaves subdirs relative to dir with `CMakeLists.txt`. @Andry's solution leaves _just_ the filename.

Answer (score 54):

**GCC** 8 now has the `-fmacro-prefix-map` and `-ffile-prefix-map` options:

> **-fmacro-prefix-map=*old*=*new***
>
> When preprocessing files residing in directory *old*, expand the `__FILE__` and `__BASE_FILE__` macros as if the files resided in directory *new* instead. This can be used to change an absolute path to a relative path by using `.` for *new* which can result in more reproducible builds that are location independent. This option also affects `__builtin_FILE()` during compilation. See also `-ffile-prefix-map`.

> **-ffile-prefix-map=*old*=*new***
>
> When compiling files residing in directory *old*, record any references
> to them in the result of the compilation as if the files resided in
> directory *new* instead. Specifying this option is equivalent to
> specifying all the individual `-f*-prefix-map` options. This can be used
> to make reproducible builds that are location independent. See also
> `-fmacro-prefix-map` and `-fdebug-prefix-map`.

Setting an invalid path for `-ffile-prefix-map` (`-fdebug-prefix-map`) will break debugging unless you tell your debugger how to map back. (gdb: `set substitue-path`, vscode: `"sourceFileMap"`).

If your intent is to only clean up `__FILE__` just use `-fmacro-prefix-map`.

Example:
So for my **Jenkins** builds I will add `-ffile-prefix-map=${WORKSPACE}/=/`, and another to remove the local dev package install prefix.

**NOTE** Unfortunately the `-ffile-prefix-map` and `-fmacro-prefix-map` options are only available in GCC 8 onwards.  For, say, GCC 5, we only have `-fdebug-prefix-map` which does not affect `__FILE__`.

Comment: Option `-ffile-prefix-map` indeed implies both `-fdebug-prefix-map` and `-fmacro-prefix-map` options. See also the references at https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/build-path/ The GCC bug that tracks `-fmacro-prefix-map` and `-ffile-prefix-map` is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70268

Comment: If your compiler supports this, like any decently recent version of GCC or Clang does, you should use this instead of the other solutions. It is so much more elegant and lightweight.

Answer (score 50):

I have just thought of a great solution to this that works with both source and header files, is very efficient and works on compile time in all platforms without compiler-specific extensions. This solution also preserves the relative directory structure of your project, so you know in which folder the file is in, and only relative to the root of your project.

The idea is to get the size of the source directory with your build tool and just add it to the `__FILE__` macro, removing the directory entirely and only showing the file name starting at your source directory.

The following example is implemented using CMake, but there's no reason it wouldn't work with any other build tools, because the trick is very simple.

On the CMakeLists.txt file, define a macro that has the length of the path to your project on CMake:

```
# The additional / is important to remove the last character from the path.
# Note that it does not matter if the OS uses / or \, because we are only
# saving the path size.
string(LENGTH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/" SOURCE_PATH_SIZE)
add_definitions("-DSOURCE_PATH_SIZE=${SOURCE_PATH_SIZE}")
```

On your source code, define a `__FILENAME__` macro that just adds the source path size to the `__FILE__` macro:

```
#define __FILENAME__ (__FILE__ + SOURCE_PATH_SIZE)
```

Then just use this new macro instead of the `__FILE__` macro. This works because the `__FILE__` path will always start with the path to your CMake source dir. By removing it from the `__FILE__` string the preprocessor will take care of specifying the correct file name and it will all be relative to the root of your CMake project.

If you care about the performance, this is as efficient as using `__FILE__`, because both `__FILE__` and `SOURCE_PATH_SIZE` are known compile time constants, so it can be optimized away by the compiler.

The only place where this would fail is if you're using this on generated files and they're on a off-source build folder. Then you'll probably have to create another macro using the `CMAKE_BUILD_DIR` variable instead of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`.

Comment: I didn't understand this at first. I coded up examples and ran them against gcc and clang and they work. I also experiment with just appending various literal numeric values, and that behaves as I expected.

Then it finally dawned on me. `__FILE__` is a pointer to an array of bytes. So adding a numeric literal is just pointer addition.

Very clever @RenatoUtsch

Comment: It works only if a source file is under cmake list directory. If a source file is outside then it will break, might with access outside of a literal string. So be careful with that.

Comment: It actually does not reduce the code size. I guess the whole path is still compiled into the binary, just the pointer is modified.

Comment: Both the `__FILE__` macro and the SOURCE_PATH_SIZE macros are constants known at compile time. I'd expect modern optimizing compilers to be able to detect that part of the string is not used and simply remove it from the binary.

Anyway, I don't think these few bytes would make a significant difference in the binary size, so I wouldn't really care about that.

Comment: @RenatoUtsch The project I'm working on has a change which just specifies the file name, but has the disadvantage of giving the C file name to the header too. The change was made in order to get reproducible builds. So with gcc with -O2, would the string be indeed optimized and the build made reproducible?

Comment: I'd expect that, but you'll have to test it out for yourself.

Comment: This is so simple and clever!

Comment: Elegant solution for single source trees. Thank you!

Comment: Changed macro to `#define __FILENAME__ ((__FILE__) + (SOURCE_PATH_SIZE))` to eliminate the clang complaint about integers being added to strings. Also added a `#ifndef SOURCE_PATH_SIZE
#define SOURCE_PATH_SIZE            0
#endif` to keep clang from thinking there is no definition. Now code shows up clean in the ide.

Answer (score 29):

- C++11
- msvc2015u3,gcc5.4,clang3.8.0
- https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aandry81%2Ftacklelib%20content%3A%22get_file_name_constexpr_offset%22&type=code

  ```
    template <typename T, size_t S>
    inline constexpr size_t get_file_name_offset(const T (& str)[S], size_t i = S - 1)
    {
        return (str[i] == '/' || str[i] == '\\') ? i + 1 : (i > 0 ? get_file_name_offset(str, i - 1) : 0);
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline constexpr size_t get_file_name_offset(T (& str)[1])
    {
        return 0;
    }
  ```

'

```
    int main()
    {
         printf("%s\n", &__FILE__[get_file_name_offset(__FILE__)]);
    }
```

Code generates a compile time offset when:

- `gcc`: at least gcc6.1 + `-O1`
- `msvc`: put result into constexpr variable:

  ```
      constexpr auto file = &__FILE__[get_file_name_offset(__FILE__)];
      printf("%s\n", file);
  ```
- `clang`: insists on not compile time evaluation

There is a trick to force all 3 compilers does compile time evaluation even in the debug configuration with disabled optimization:

```
    namespace utility {

        template <typename T, T v>
        struct const_expr_value
        {
            static constexpr const T value = v;
        };

    }

    #define UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE(exp) ::utility::const_expr_value<decltype(exp), exp>::value

    int main()
    {
         printf("%s\n", &__FILE__[UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE(get_file_name_offset(__FILE__))]);
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/u6s8j3

Comment: You can define one more helper macro `#define LEAF(FN) (&FN[UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE(get_file_name_offset(FN))])` and use it like this `printf("%s\n", LEAF(__FILE__));`

Comment: This should be the answer.
It doesn't require cmake, modifying the makefile, or runtime computation. And it can be used by a new __FILENAME__ macro to make it intuitive: `#define __FILENAME__ (__FILE__ + get_file_name_offset(__FILE__))`

Comment: Note, that "utility" is also a namespace used by c++ std, so you might need to rename the namespace or msvc/the compiler might produce very weird errors. For me it produced errors with missing const.
I used the LEAF macro to keep things more sane.

Answer (score 27):

At least for gcc, the value of `__FILE__` is the file path *as specified on the compiler's command line*. If you compile `file.c` like this:

```
gcc -c /full/path/to/file.c
```

the `__FILE__` will expand to `"/full/path/to/file.c"`. If you instead do this:

```
cd /full/path/to
gcc -c file.c
```

then `__FILE__` will expand to just `"file.c"`.

This may or may not be practical.

The C standard does not require this behavior. All it says about `__FILE__` is that it expands to "The presumed name of the current source ﬁle (a character string literal)".

An alternative is to use the `#line` directive. It overrides the current line number, and optionally the source file name. If you want to override the file name but leave the line number alone, use the `__LINE__` macro.

For example, you can add this near the top of `file.c`:

```
#line __LINE__ "file.c"
```

The only problem with this is that it assigns the specified line number to the *following* line, and the first argument to `#line` has to be a *digit-sequence* so you can't do something like

```
#line (__LINE__-1) "file.c"  // This is invalid
```

Ensuring that the file name in the `#line` directive matches the actual name of the file is left as an exercise.

At least for gcc, this will also affect the file name reported in diagnostic messages.

Comment: Keith Thompson it is great solution, thank You. The only problem is that it seems that this macro cuts `__LINE__` value by one. So `__LINE__` written in line `x` gest evaluated to `x-1`. At least with gcc 5.4.

Comment: @Klepak: You're right, and that's standard behavior. The directive "causes the implementation to behave as if the following sequence of source lines begins
with a source line that has a line number as specified by the digit sequence". And it has to be a *digit-sequence*, so you can't use `#line __LINE__-1, "file.c"`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: How would it be for other compilers like Clang, MSVC, or Intel C Compiler?

Comment: At line 0 of a file, I just do: `#line 2 "name.cpp"`. Also as a side note it is nice to know that it does not contaminate other files that `#include` it (at least on MSVC)

Answer (score 21):

Purely compile time solution here. It's based on the fact that `sizeof()` of a string literal returns its length+1.

```
#define STRIPPATH(s)\
    (sizeof(s) > 2 && (s)[sizeof(s)-2] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 1 : \
    sizeof(s) > 3 && (s)[sizeof(s)-3] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 2 : \
    sizeof(s) > 4 && (s)[sizeof(s)-4] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 3 : \
    sizeof(s) > 5 && (s)[sizeof(s)-5] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 4 : \
    sizeof(s) > 6 && (s)[sizeof(s)-6] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 5 : \
    sizeof(s) > 7 && (s)[sizeof(s)-7] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 6 : \
    sizeof(s) > 8 && (s)[sizeof(s)-8] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 7 : \
    sizeof(s) > 9 && (s)[sizeof(s)-9] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 8 : \
    sizeof(s) > 10 && (s)[sizeof(s)-10] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 9 : \
    sizeof(s) > 11 && (s)[sizeof(s)-11] == '/' ? (s) + sizeof(s) - 10 : (s))

#define __JUSTFILE__ STRIPPATH(__FILE__)
```

Feel free to extend the conditional operator cascade to the maximum sensible file name in the project. Path length doesn't matter, as long as you check far enough from the end of the string.

I'll see if I can get a similar macro with no hard-coded length with macro recursion...

Comment: Cool answer. You need to use at least `-O1` to use this to be compile-time.

Comment: Isn't this backwards? You want to find the *last* occurrence of '/', which means you should start with the `sizeof(s) > 2` check first. Also, this did not work at compile-time for me, at -Os. The full path strings were present in the output binary.

Comment: Nope this is not purely compile time solution.

Comment: @Hadatko please elaborate. What exactly makes this _not_ purely compile time in your view?

Answer (score 13):

Recent Clang compiler has a `__FILE_NAME__` macro (see [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-macros)).

Comment: seems that gcc has [added it](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=1a9b3f04c11eb467a8dc504a37dad57a371a0d4c), too

Answer (score 9):

In VC, when using `/FC`, `__FILE__` expands to the full path, without the `/FC` option `__FILE__` expands file name. ref: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fc-full-path-of-source-code-file-in-diagnostics?view=vs-2019)

Comment: in VS2019, `/FC` is forced if using the [Edit & Continue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2019) `/ZI` d/b.

Comment: Without the /FC option, `__FILE__` uses the relative path instead of the absolute path. Although it is shorter, it is not a "file name without path"  solution.

Comment: At least in VS2019 & VS2022 the default for the underlying setting in the project files (`UseFullPaths`) defaults to `true` unless overridden at a more local level (such as in the project file). See `Microsoft.Cl.Common.props` ...

Answer (score 9):

I have use the same solution with @Patrick 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16658858/844843) for years.

It has a small issue when the full path contains symbol-link.

### Better solution.

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D'__FILE__=\"$(subst $(realpath ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})/,,$(abspath $<))\"'")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D'__FILE__=\"$(subst $(realpath ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})/,,$(abspath $<))\"'")
```

### Why should use this ?

- `-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined` to mute the compiler warnings for redefining `__FILE__` macro.

  > For those compilers do not support this, refer to the *Robust way* below.
- Strip the project path from the file path is your *real* requirement. You won't like to waste the time to find out where is a `header.h` file, `src/foo/header.h` or `src/bar/header.h`.
- We should strip the `__FILE__` macro in `cmake` config file.

  This macro is used in most exists codes. Simply redefine it can set you free.

  Compilers like `gcc` predefines this macro from the command line arguments. And the full path is written in `makefile`s generated by `cmake`.
- **Hard code in `CMAKE_*_FLAGS` is required.**

  There is some commands to add compiler options or definitions in some more recently version, like `add_definitions()` and `add_compile_definitions()`. These commands will parse the make functions like `subst` before apply to source files. That is not we want.

### Robust way for `-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined`.

```
include(CheckCCompilerFlag)
check_c_compiler_flag(-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined SUPPORT_C_WNO_BUILTIN_MACRO_REDEFINED)
if (SUPPORT_C_WNO_BUILTIN_MACRO_REDEFINED)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined")
endif (SUPPORT_C_WNO_BUILTIN_MACRO_REDEFINED)
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined SUPPORT_CXX_WNO_BUILTIN_MACRO_REDEFINED)
if (SUPPORT_CXX_WNO_BUILTIN_MACRO_REDEFINED)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined")
endif (SUPPORT_CXX_WNO_BUILTIN_MACRO_REDEFINED)
```

> Remember to remove this compiler option from the `set(*_FLAGS ... -D__FILE__=...)` line.

Comment: This does not work for contents coming from include files.

Comment: can you post some code? A common case is to set variables in local scope and use it in another.

Comment: For example if you use `__FILE__` with your definition to produce a diagnostic in an inline function defined in a header file, the runtime diagnostic will report the name of the file passed to the compiler instead of the name of the include file, whereas the line number would refer to the include file.

Comment: yes, it designed to be that, for the most common usage is `#define LOG(fmt, args...) printf("%s " fmt, __FILE__, ##args)`. when using the `LOG()` macro, you do not really want to see `log.h` in messages. after all, the `__FILE__` macro is expanded in every C/Cpp file (compile unit) instead of the included files.

Answer (score 9):

For Visual Studio, you can use the `/d1trimfile` option.

You might want to set it to `/d1trimfile:"$(SolutionDir)\"`:

[image: magic]

**NB:** Explanation for the trailing `\` right before the `"`:

> *To escape the first one* (`$(SolutionDir)` ends in a backslash)*, otherwise the quote is escaped. You need an even amount of backslashes
> before the quote.*

Answer (score 8):

This behaviour has been implemented in some compilers, you can get basename of the compiled file by using:

- **GCC**: Macro [`__FILE_NAME__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros) (since [GCC 12](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42579))
- **Clang**: Macro [`__FILE_NAME__`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-macros) (since [CLANG 9.0.0](https://reviews.llvm.org/D61756))
- **MSVC**: Unfortunately, as state in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-of-base-file-macro/362078), no support of this kind of macro is planned

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution available with C++14 or newer that uses compile-time calculation:

```
constexpr auto* getFileName(const char* const path)
{
    const auto* startPosition = path;
    for (const auto* currentCharacter = path;*currentCharacter != '\0'; ++currentCharacter)
    {
        if (*currentCharacter == '\\' || *currentCharacter == '/')
        {
            startPosition = currentCharacter;
        }
    }

    if (startPosition != path)
    {
        ++startPosition;
    }

    return startPosition;
}

std::cout << getFileName(__FILE__);
```

Comment: Great solution. Usable earlier to C++11 ?

Comment: @Jesko Unfortunately constexpr is a must here, so it won't work for earlier standards

Comment: @Jesko This isn't even usable in C++11. This starts being usable with C++14. ("'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension")

Answer (score 4):

Use the [basename()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) function, or, if you are on Windows, [_splitpath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx).

```
#include <libgen.h>

#define PRINTFILE() { char buf[] = __FILE__; printf("Filename:  %s\n", basename(buf)); }
```

Also try `man 3 basename` in a shell.

Comment: @mahmood: `char file_copy[] = __FILE__; const char *filename = basename(__FILE__);`. The reason for the copy is that basename can modify the input string. You also have to watch out that the result pointer is only good until `basename` is called again. This means it isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @SteveJessop, ah I forgot. True.

Comment: @Amigable: to be fair, I suspect that `basename` in fact will not modify the input string that results from `__FILE__`, because the input string doesn't have a `/` at the end and so there's no need for modification. So you might get away with it, but I figure the first time someone sees `basename`, they should see it with all the restrictions.

Comment: @SteveJessop the BSd man page for basename() mention that legacy version of basename() takes a const char* and does not modify the string. The linux man page mentions nothing about const but mentions that it can return a part of the argument string. So, best be conservative dealing with basename().

Comment: @SteveJessop, hehe, I only *now* after looking at your comment carefully, after four years, **realize** that `/` at the end of the string means basename may have a good reason to modify its argument.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `CMAKE` with GNU compiler this `global` define works fine:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D__MY_FILE__='\"$(notdir $(abspath $<))\"'")
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no compile time way to do this. Obviously you can do it at runtime using the C runtime, as some of the other answers have demonstrated, but at compile time, when the pre-procesor kicks in, you're out of luck.

Comment: the `strrchr` answer could plausibly be computed at compile-time, although of course still not by the preprocessor. I don't know whether gcc actually does it, I haven't checked, but I'm pretty sure that it does compute `strlen` of string literals at compile-time.

Comment: @Steve - maybe, but that's a big dependency on compiler specific behaviour.

Comment: I don't think it is a big dependency, because I very much doubt that this code is performance-critical. And if it is, move it out of the loop. In cases where this is a huge deal, because you absolutely need a string literal containing just the basename, you could perhaps compute the right string at *build* time by running some script over the source.

Comment: It may not be performance critical, but it can easily be seen as privacy critical. There's no real good reason for revealing my per-customer organizational practices in strings frozen into a released EXE file. Worse, for applications created on behalf of a customer, those strings might reveal things my customer might prefer not to, such as not being the author of their own product. Since `__FILE__` is invoked implicitly by `assert()`, this leak can occur without any other overt act.

Comment: @RBerteig the basename of `__FILE__` itself may also reveal things the customer might prefer not to, so using `__FILE__` anywhere at all -- whether it contains the full absolute pathname or just the basename -- has the same issues that you pointed out. In this situation all output will need to be scrutinized and a special API should be introduced for output to customers. The rest of the output should be dumped to /dev/NULL or stdout and stderr should be closed. :-)

Comment: There *is* a way to do it purely on compile time, you just need to be a little bit smart with the build configuration. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation on what @red1ynx proposed would to be create the following macro:

```
#define SET_THIS_FILE_NAME() \
    static const char* const THIS_FILE_NAME = \
        strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__;
```

In each of your .c(pp) files add:

```
SET_THIS_FILE_NAME();
```

Then you can refer to `THIS_FILE_NAME` instead of `__FILE__`:

```
printf("%s\n", THIS_FILE_NAME);
```

This means the construction is performed once per .c(pp) file instead of each time the macro is referenced.

It is limited to use only from .c(pp) files and would be unusable from header files.

Answer (score 3):

just hope to improve FILE macro a bit:

`#define FILE (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__)`

this catches / and \, like Czarek Tomczak requested, and this works great in my mixed environment.

Comment: Defining a macro named `FILE` is a really bad idea if you include `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: good to know. i just wanted to show Czarek my \\ / solution, so i don't bothered with naming schemes.

Comment: The answer doesn't always work if `__FILE__` contains mixed separators e.g. `c:\abc/xyz\file.h`.

Answer (score 3):

I did a macro `__FILENAME__` that avoids cutting full path each time. The issue is to hold the resulting file name in a cpp-local variable.

It can be easily done by defining a static global variable in **.h** file.
This definition gives separate and independent variables in each **.cpp** file that includes the **.h**.
In order to be a multithreading-proof it worth to make the variable(s) also thread local (TLS).

One variable stores the File Name (shrunk). Another holds the non-cut value that `__FILE__` gave. The h file:

```
static __declspec( thread ) const char* fileAndThreadLocal_strFilePath = NULL;
static __declspec( thread ) const char* fileAndThreadLocal_strFileName = NULL;
```

The macro itself calls method with all the logic:

```
#define __FILENAME__ \
    GetSourceFileName(__FILE__, fileAndThreadLocal_strFilePath, fileAndThreadLocal_strFileName)
```

And the function is implemented this way:

```
const char* GetSourceFileName(const char* strFilePath, 
                              const char*& rstrFilePathHolder, 
                              const char*& rstrFileNameHolder)
{
    if(strFilePath != rstrFilePathHolder)
    {
        // 
        // This if works in 2 cases: 
        // - when first time called in the cpp (ordinary case) or
        // - when the macro __FILENAME__ is used in both h and cpp files 
        //   and so the method is consequentially called 
        //     once with strFilePath == "UserPath/HeaderFileThatUsesMyMACRO.h" and 
        //     once with strFilePath == "UserPath/CPPFileThatUsesMyMACRO.cpp"
        //
        rstrFileNameHolder = removePath(strFilePath);
        rstrFilePathHolder = strFilePath;
    }
    return rstrFileNameHolder;
}
```

The removePath() can be implemented in different ways, but the fast and simple seems to be with strrchr:

```
const char* removePath(const char* path)
{
    const char* pDelimeter = strrchr (path, '\\');
    if (pDelimeter)
        path = pDelimeter+1;

    pDelimeter = strrchr (path, '/');
    if (pDelimeter)
        path = pDelimeter+1;

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
#pragma push_macro("__FILE__")
#define __FILE__ "foobar.c"
```

after the include statements in your source file and add

```
#pragma pop_macro("__FILE__")
```

at the end of your source file.

Comment: `push_macro` and `pop_macro` are non-standard.  (gcc supports them for compatibility with Microsoft Windows compilers.) In any case, there's no point in pushing and popping the definition of `__FILE__`; the restored value won't be used after the end of the source file anyway. A cleaner way to change the value of `__FILE__` is `#line __LINE__ "foobar.c"`

Comment: And this causes an internal error in gcc's preprocessor. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69665

Answer (score 2):

Here is a portable function that works for both Linux (path '/') and Windows (mix of '\' and  '/'). 
 Compiles with gcc, clang and vs.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* GetFileName(const char *path)
{
    const char *name = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    if (path && *path) {
        name = strrchr(path, '/');
        tmp = strrchr(path, '\\');
        if (tmp) {
             return name && name > tmp ? name + 1 : tmp + 1;
        }
    }
    return name ? name + 1 : path;
}

int main() {
    const char *name = NULL, *path = NULL;

    path = __FILE__;
    name = GetFileName(path);
    printf("path: %s, filename: %s\n", path, name);

    path ="/tmp/device.log";
    name = GetFileName(path);
    printf("path: %s, filename: %s\n", path, name);

    path = "C:\\Downloads\\crisis.avi";
    name = GetFileName(path);
    printf("path: %s, filename: %s\n", path, name);

    path = "C:\\Downloads/nda.pdf";
    name = GetFileName(path);
    printf("path: %s, filename: %s\n", path, name);

    path = "C:/Downloads\\word.doc";
    name = GetFileName(path);
    printf("path: %s, filename: %s\n", path, name);

    path = NULL;
    name = GetFileName(NULL);
    printf("path: %s, filename: %s\n", path, name);

    path = "";
    name = GetFileName("");
    printf("path: %s, filename: %s\n", path, name);

    return 0;
}
```

Standard output:

```
path: test.c, filename: test.c
path: /tmp/device.log, filename: device.log
path: C:\Downloads\crisis.avi, filename: crisis.avi
path: C:\Downloads/nda.pdf, filename: nda.pdf
path: C:/Downloads\word.doc, filename: word.doc
path: (null), filename: (null)
path: , filename:
```

Answer (score 2):

If you ended up on this page looking for a way to remove absolute source path that is pointing to ugly build location from the binary that you are shipping, below might suit your needs.

Although this doesn't produce exactly the answer that the author has expressed his wish for **since it assumes the use of CMake**, it gets pretty close. It's a pity this wasn't mentioned earlier by anyone as it would have saved me loads of time.

```
OPTION(CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS "If true, cmake will use relative paths" ON)
```

Setting above variable to `ON` will generate build command in the format:

```
cd /ugly/absolute/path/to/project/build/src && 
    gcc <.. other flags ..> -c ../../src/path/to/source.c
```

As a result, `__FILE__` macro will resolve to `../../src/path/to/source.c`

[CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS.html)

Beware of the warning on the documentation page though:

> Use relative paths (May not work!).

It is not guaranteed to work in all cases, but worked in mine - CMake 3.13 + gcc 4.5

Comment: CMake 3.4+ documentation states that "This variable has no effect. The partially implemented effect it had in previous releases was removed in CMake 3.4." If it worked for you with 3.13, there's another reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

A short, working answer for both Windows and *nix:

```
#define __FILENAME__ std::max<const char*>(__FILE__,\
    std::max(strrchr(__FILE__, '\\')+1, strrchr(__FILE__, '/')+1))
```

Comment: Why do you need `std::max<const char*>` instead of just `std::max`?

Comment: Good solution except `std::max` requires `<algorithm>` which I would rather not include in a header file. Another option can be checking platform by `#ifdef _WIN32` since `__FILE__` will have consistent separator characters.

Comment: @Burak then any other simple "max" function will suffice. #define PATH_SEPARATOR will also help of course.

Answer (score 2):

In MSVC, add **FILENAME** macro as **FILENAME**=%(FileName)%(Extension) to the Preprocessor Definitions of the C++ project. I'm afraid this is completely a compiler killer. Somehow it breaks parallel build.

Comment: The fact that the question uses "/" as path separator points to a non-Windows compiler. I doubt @mahmood was using MSVC; some comments state he was using gcc but I could not locate where he said so.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works for environments that don't have the string library (Linux kernel, embedded systems, etc):

```
#define FILENAME ({ \
    const char* filename_start = __FILE__; \
    const char* filename = filename_start; \
    while(*filename != '\0') \
        filename++; \
    while((filename != filename_start) && (*(filename - 1) != '/')) \
        filename--; \
    filename; })
```

Now just use `FILENAME` instead of `__FILENAME__`. Yes, it's still a runtime thing but it works.

Comment: May want to check both '/' and '\', depending on platform.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using GCC, you can [take advantage](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) of

> `__BASE_FILE__` This macro expands to the name of the main input file, in the form of a C string constant. This is the source file that was
>   specified on the command line of the preprocessor or C compiler

and then control how you want to display the filename by changing the source file representation (full path/relative path/basename) at compilation time.

Comment: makes no difference. I used `__FILE__` and `__BASE_FILE__` however they both show full path to file

Comment: how do you invoke the compiler ?

Comment: Then I bet SCONS is calling gcc like this `gcc /absolute/path/to/file.c`. If you find a way to change this behavior (opening another question on SO, lol?), you do not need to modify the string at runtime

Comment: This answer is 100% wrong. `__BASE_FILE__` (as the docs say, albeit unclearly) produces the name of *the file specified on the command line*, e.g. `test.c` or `/tmp/test.c` depending on how you invoked the compiler. That's exactly the same thing as `__FILE__`, except if you're inside a header file, in which case `__FILE__` produces the name of the current file (e.g. `foo.h`) whereas `__BASE_FILE__` continues to produce `test.c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string f( __FILE__ );
f = string( (find(f.rbegin(), f.rend(), '/')+1).base() + 1, f.end() );

// searches for the '/' from the back, transfers the reverse iterator 
// into a forward iterator and constructs a new sting with both
```

Answer (score 0):

A tweaked, even more "bloated" version of red1ynx's answer:

```
#define __FILENAME__ \
  (strchr(__FILE__, '\\') \
  ? ((strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__)) \
  : ((strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__)))
```

If we find backslashes, we split on backslashes. Otherwise, split on forward slash. Simple enough.

Just about any alternative would be cleaner (A C++ constexpr is really the gold standard here, in my opinion). However, this may be helpful if you're using some compiler where `__BASE_FILE__` isn't available.

Comment: Why should you search for backslashes first? If `__FILE__` contains mixed separators, e.g. `c:\abc\xyz/file.h`, then the macro does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better than using strrchr function.
strfnchr will search last delemeter '/'  and get filename from `__FILE__`
and you can use `__FILE__NAME__` instead `__FILE__` for get file name without full file path.
strrchr solution searching filename twice per use. but this code is just 1 time search.
And it works effectively even if there is no seperater '/' in `__FILE__`.
You can use it by replacing it with \ as needed.
The source code of strfnchr was improved by using the source code of strrchr below. I think it will work more effectively than strrchr.
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strrchr.c.html

```
inline const char* strfnchr(const char* s, int c) {
  const char* found = s;
  while (*(s++)) {
    if (*s == c)
      found = s;
  }
  if (found != s)
    return found + 1;
  return s;
}

#define __FILE_NAME__ strfnchr(__FILE__, '/')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on @RenatoUtsch answer:

CMake list:

```
string(LENGTH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/" SOURCE_PATH_SIZE)
add_definitions("-DSOURCE_PATH_SIZE=${SOURCE_PATH_SIZE}")
add_definitions("-DSOURCE_PATH=\"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\"")
```

C/C++ header

```
#define __FILENAME__ strstr(__FILE__, SOURCE_PATH) + SOURCE_PATH_SIZE
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is not good enough for it's not a compile-time const expression
Here is a really simple solution:

```
 #define FILESTEM(x)                                                        \
  std::string_view(x).substr(std::string_view(x).rfind(OS_PATH_SLASH) + 1, \
                             std::string_view(x).rfind('.') -              \
                                 std::string_view(x).rfind(OS_PATH_SLASH) - 1)
```

it's a constexpr and can use in header file.

Comment: This is a C++ solution.  The OP asked in a 'C' environment.  This doesn't work for a 'C' program.