# base file name from __FILE__

Tags: c++, windows, macros, predefined-macro

I need the file name only where the `__FILE__` and `__FILEW__` macros return the whole path.

I defined the following:

```
#define __FILE_NAME_ONLY__ (strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__)
```

I am using it as follows:

```
#define MY_TRACE( mask, format, ... )  \            
            GlobalTrace( mask, L"-[" __FILE_NAME_ONLY__ L":" format , __VA_ARGS__ )
```

I get the following error:

**error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments**

and when I try the following macros:

```
#define __WIDE(_String) L ## _String
#define _WIDE(_String) __WIDE(_String)
```

as follows

```
 #define MY_TRACE( mask, format, ... )  \            
                GlobalTrace( mask, L"-[" _WIDE(__FILE_NAME_ONLY__) L":" format , __VA_ARGS__ )
```

I get : **error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'L'**  when I actually try to use the MY_TRACE macro

what am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're depending on string literal concatenation, except that all of the terms aren't string literals.

I assume you were previously doing it like so:

```
#define MY_TRACE( mask, format, ... )  \            
            GlobalTrace( mask, L"-[" __FILE__ L":" format , __VA_ARGS__ )
```

If `__FILE__` and `format` expand to a string literal, the 4 strings get pasted together into one. `"A" "B" "C" "D"` is the same as `"ABCD"`.

That doesn't happen when you replace with `__FILE_NAME_ONLY__` because it expands to a function call, not a literal.

Comment: well before I was using `__FILEW__` because of wide string

Comment: @Saher it doesn't matter, they both evaluate as string literals. Just different kinds of strings.

Comment: so how to get that to work `__FILE_NAME_ONLY__(__FILE__)` didn't solve it

Comment: @Saher convert the strings to `wstring` and use the concatenation operator `+`.

Comment: hmmm I think it should work somehow without this conversion. What I have above is an example. I am using / concatenating many other values which work fine and now I would need to convert everything. I prefer just to get this working if possible

Comment: @Saher what you *think* is irrelevant. I told you why it doesn't work, and I gave you a suggestion to make it work. You can choose not to believe me, but good luck getting a better answer.

Comment: I guess my question is how come `_WIDE(__FILEW_)` works while `__FILE_NAME_ONLY(__FILE__)` doesn't? they are similar to me both are function calls.

Comment: @Saher `_WIDE()` isn't a function call, it's another macro. The rules for macros are completely different to the rules for functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using gcc this macro should help:

```
__BASE_FILE__
```

Here's a helpful [list](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros)

Comment: +1 to reset from -1 score. Not the worlds greatest answer, (like "*42*") but it's not bad - some GCC using Windows people may be helped by it.

Comment: Good to know that helping people isn't a popularity contest ;)