# CMake C/C++ macro generating

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I use `__FILE__` during logging and debug my program. And when I use it, I get full source file path. So, I wanna write my own macro similar the macro `__FILE__`.

I looked for a solution, but I found nothing about it. 
So, does it exist a CMake way to implement user macro, that will be generate something data similar the `__FILE__` macro?

Comment: Why not just use `__FILE__` then?

Comment: __FILE__ prints full file path, but It looks very big and ugly in logs.

Comment: I guess you can create a custom command that loops over all source files of a target and adds a compiler flag `-DFILE=${SOURCE_FILE_NAME}` after extracting the `${SOURCE_FILE_NAME}` variable based on the file path.

Comment: That's a golden XY problem. Just process the value of `__FILE__` before logging it :)

Comment: @Corristo I was thinking of that. It seems like this would be simpler to solve in c++ than CMake..

Comment: @drescherjm I think, that C++ source doesn't have to know about project structure.

Comment: It does not have to do that. All it needs is to do remove the path from `__FILE__` leaving just the file name. You can certainly write a c or c++ function that removes the path.

Comment: [`__FILE__` in MSVC prints the basename by default unless you specify `/FC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path for my platform

Comment: This is now closed, but you can very well extract the basename at compile-time without build system trickery: https://godbolt.org/g/egaQcs (notice `offset .L.str.1+59` where `59` is hardcoded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment already, you can create a CMake function that loops over all source files of a given target and adds a macro definition to the compile flags for that source file.

```
function(add_filepath_macro target) 
    get_target_property(SOURCE_FILES ${target} SOURCES)

    foreach (FILE_PATH IN LISTS SOURCE_FILES)
        file(RELATIVE_PATH RELATIVE_FILE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_PATH})
        set_property(SOURCE ${FILE_PATH} APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS FILEPATH="${RELATIVE_FILE_PATH}")
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

This now defines the macro `FILEPATH` in every TU that is part of the target you pass to it.

There is one caveat though: In contrast to the regular `__FILE__` macro you **can't** use the `FILEPATH` macro in header files, because including one such header in different translation units immediately causes an ODR violation and thus undefined behaviour.

#### Demo

Let's see how this works for a very small example. Start with the following project structure:

```
.
├── cmake
│   └── add_filepath_macro.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   ├── a.cpp
│   ├── a.h
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

The `cmake/add_filepath_macro.cmake` file contains nothing but the code shown above.

The we have the library files

```
// lib/a.h
#pragma once
char const* foo();

// lib/a.cpp
#include "a.h"
char const* foo() {
    return FILEPATH;
}
```

with corresponding `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# lib/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(liba
    a.cpp
)

target_include_directories(liba PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_filepath_macro(liba)
```

as well as a small demo executable

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "a.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << foo() << '\n' << FILEPATH << '\n';
}
```

and finally the project `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# CMakeLists.txt

# not tested with older version, but I guess it should work with anything > 3.0
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9) 

project(cmake_filepath_macro_demo LANGUAGE CXX)

include(cmake/add_filepath_macro.cmake)
add_subdirectory(lib)

add_executable(demo
    main.cpp
)

add_filepath_macro(demo)
```

Running the resulting executable then produces the following output

```
$ ./demo 
lib/a.cpp
main.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the path from `__FILE__`.

Possible solution:

```
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG(message) \
do { \
    char* filename = basename(__FILE__); \
    printf("In %s: %s", filename, message); \
} while(false);
```

Example has to be extended by check of log level. And instead of a fixed message a variadic number of arguments should be used.

Note: This is for Unix. Assume your OS provides a similar function.

Comment: it's ok, but I wanna source path be calculated in compile time