# Fixed format Fortran with __FILE__ and Gfortran

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, gfortran, intel-mkl

We got a large framework written in Fortran fixed format (*.f) files - where we have a lot of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to print errors, warnings etc at run time. We have so far only used `ifort` and there has been no problem using the `-fpp` flag for the macros used.

Now we are looking to use `gfortran` by GNU and the problem has emerged where the macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` and many line do exceed the 72 column limit for the fixed format. We think `gfortran` with `cpp` prints the entire path to the file when using `__FILE__`, which quite easily can make the 72 column limit easily exceeded.

The one option we have tried is to use `-ffixed-line-length-none` which seems to overcome the latter issue but in turn create the following problem

```
 Error: Expected expression at (1) in PARAMETER statement
 mkl_vsl.f90:711:72:
```

`mkl_vsl` is the MKL VSL library by `intel` and line 711 looks like this:

```
  PARAMETER (VSL_RNG_METHOD_EXPONENTIAL_ICDF_ACCURATE=              &
 &IOR(VSL_RNG_METHOD_EXPONENTIAL_ICDF,VSL_RNG_METHOD_ACCURACY_FLAG))
```

Is there a way to truncate `__FILE__` so it only prints the filename rather than the entire path?

Comment: The problem is that this occurs a few hundred times - is there a way to truncate `__FILE__` so it only prints the filename rather than the entire path

Comment: If you include a `.f90` (even in the "intersection form") file into a `.f` file, you are doing at at your own risk. Doesn't Intel offer some `.f` to include instead?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path

Comment: However, on my computer, `__FILE__` does actually print only the relative file name, not the full path, only the relative path.

Comment: Thanks, @VladimirF. Yes that might be the case , but what if a specific fortran file is in some deep subfolder? Would it still be the same . 
Also, I think `-fmacro-prefix-map` is unfortunately only valid for gcc and g++

Comment: Yes, that option is only valid for C/C++/ObjC/ObjC++ but not for Fortran.

Comment: You are on your own really, normally the solution is `-ffixed-line-length-none`. If that does not work with your include file, try to find solution to that problem. Intel should offer some solution.

Comment: If nothing else, you can fall back on running the preprocessor to give you intermediate files which you then process again as you like (to shorten lines, etc.) and then pass them to your compiler.

Comment: Okay thanks. The best solution is to change the file which includes the "mkl_vsl" to a *.f90 file