# Using -ffile-prefix-map breaks debugging

Tags: gcc, gdb, binary-reproducibility

At $DAYJOB, I am trying to implement reproducible builds to make debugging released software where we no longer have the full debug versions on our build servers easier, using the tips from [reproducible-builds.org](https://reproducible-builds.org).

Using the [-ffile-prefix-map=/path/to/build=src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848526) option in GCC to [avoid leaking internal file paths](https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/build-path/) does help making some error messages cleaner, but does produce problems when using GDB. I am in /path/to/build/some/binary/ and hitting a breakpoint in /path/to/build/lib/cclib/:

```
Breakpoint 1, [...]
at src/lib/cclib/eventloop.cc:154
154    src/lib/cclib/eventloop.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

As a workaround, I can symlink `src` to the root of the build tree, but is there a better way to make sure gdb understands the mapping?

Comment: Try adding the build directory to the [source path](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#index-default-source-path-substitution) (with the `directory` command).

Comment: I guess I would also need to remove the `src` component from the rewrite, since this does not actually exist (unless the source repo is checked out as `src`)?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77092371/using-ffile-prefix-map-with-objdump-s/77093659) for an additional insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GDB has a few configuration commands to direct the way it searches for source code. In your case, where you have a tree of source code and you need to change a path prefix, [set substitute-path *DWARF-compilation-dir* *actual-dir*](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#set-substitute_002dpath) should be all you need to do.

```
set substitute-path src /path/to/build
```

Comment: That did not work with my setup, until I changed the remapping to `-ffile-prefix-map=/path/to/build=/src`, i.e., adding a leading slash to the source.
With that change, `set substitute-path /src /path/to/build` works fine!