# Using -ffile-prefix-map with objdump -S

Tags: gcc, gdb, objdump

In order to get reproducible builds, we use the `--ffile-prefix-map=/path/to/src=SRC --file-prefix-map=/path/to/lib=LIB` option when compiling. And similarly, for `gdb` I can `set substitute-path SRC=/path/to/src` etc.

However, I cannot figure out how to do a similar thing with `objdump -S`. I can work around it with a small maze of symlinks, but I don't understand the `--prefix` option to `objdump`, or know if it is the right thing to use. I tried `--prefix-strip=1 --prefix=/path/to/src` but it did not seem to do what I expected (well, it didn't manage to include any source code!)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please, let me know does the trivial example provided in my answer below work as expected in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of experimentation and a quick insight into the [source code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=binutils/objdump.c;h=608134265669d724cca54c605c553abc9fc58944;hb=HEAD#l2180) of the `objdump` utility, just to make sure I got it all right from `objdump(1)`, I managed to achieve the desired outcome.  This is probably going to be puzzling because I did nothing special, yet it all worked out as expected.

First, I created a simple "Hello, world!" program in a file named `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

Got it compiled using the following command:

```bash
gcc -Wall -ggdb -ffile-prefix-map=/path/to/cwd=/src test.c -o test
```

Using `strings test | grep /src` verified that `/src` actually got into the resulting `test` binary, so it was time to get `objdump -S` to find the source code, using the following command:

```bash
objdump -S --prefix=/path/to/cwd --prefix-strip=1 test
```

Here's an excerpt from the produced output, which shows the desired source code fragments in the disassembled code:

```
0000000000000744 <main>:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 744:   a9be7bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-32]!
 748:   910003fd    mov x29, sp
 74c:   b9001fe0    str w0, [sp, #28]
 750:   f9000be1    str x1, [sp, #16]
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
 754:   90000000    adrp    x0, 0 <__abi_tag-0x278>
 758:   91204000    add x0, x0, #0x810
 75c:   97ffffb1    bl  620 <puts@plt>
 760:   52800000    mov w0, #0x0                    // #0
}
 764:   a8c27bfd    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #32
 768:   d65f03c0    ret
 76c:   d503201f    nop
```

Thus, it must be that something isn't exactly right in the environment you're using.  Perhaps it would be good to try reproducing a simple example like this one first, to see will it work as expected.  I hope this helps.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191647/using-ffile-prefix-map-breaks-debugging) for an additional insight.