# std::source_location - filename only, not full path - compile-time substring?

Tags: c++, string, constexpr, compile-time

Is there any way to make a substring at compile time, and **NOT** store the original string in the binary ?

I'm using `std::experimental::source_location`, and really only need the filename, and not the full path, which ends up taking lots of space in the binary

Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/source_location>

consteval std::string_view filename_only(
    std::experimental::source_location location = std::experimental::source_location::current())
{
    std::string_view s = location.file_name();
    return s.substr(s.find_last_of('/')+1);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "File: " << filename_only() << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TqE7T87j3

The full string "/app/example.cpp" is stored, but only the file name is needed, so "/app/" is wasted memory.

Comment: Although not really relevant to your question, what compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc-arm-none-eabi 11.2

Comment: My guess would be that as you're using `std::string_view` which is only a reference to some original string the compiler can't get rid of the original string. If you use `std::string` instead the compiler might be able to do what you want (assuming your standard library supports constexpr std::string)

Comment: When I try to use `std::string`, I run into this error: `'location' is not a constant expression`

Comment: If you just really need to *get this done* — and it's okay to inject another tool in your toolchain — you could run the C preprocessor against your file, then post-process that output to rework the offending strings (I'd use Python, or sed, or awk, or whatever you find suitable as a post-pre-processor), then continue the rest of the compiling, assembling, and linking of the toolchain.  It's an outside-the-box Big Hammer™.

Comment: This C++ feature is still quite poorly supported, so would use it only for toy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848526/6386478), I ended up using the `__FILE__` macro combined with the `-fmacro-prefix-map` compiler option, instead of `source_location`.

So I essentially use the following code

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#define ERROR_LOG(s) log_impl(s, __FILE__, __LINE__);

void log_impl(const char* s, const char* file_name, uint16_t line)
{
    printf("%s:%i\t\t%s", file_name, line, s);
}

int main()
{
    ERROR_LOG("Uh-oh.")
}
```

with the following compiler option:

```
-fmacro-prefix-map=${SOURCE_DIR}/=/
```

I can verify that the constant strings stored in the binary do not include the full file path, as they did before, which was my objective.

Note that starting from GCC12, the macro `__FILE_NAME__` should be available, making the use of the `-fmacro-prefix-map` option redundant. I'm not using gcc 12 just yet, so the solution above is adequate.