# C Macro with a function errors out: expression cannot be used as a function

Tags: c, macros

Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path), I am trying to write my Macro that uses a function inside, and fail:

```
#include <string.h>

// Define a helper macro to get the file name from __FILE__
#define FILENAME_ONLY(file) (strrchr(file, '/') ? strrchr(file, '/') + 1 : file)

// Use the helper macro to create MYFILENAME
#define MYFILENAME FILENAME_ONLY(__FILE__)

// Create __MYFILE__ macro
#define __MYFILE__ "[" MYFILENAME "]"

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", __MYFILE__);
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
main.cpp:4:80: error: expression cannot be used as a function
 #define FILENAME_ONLY(file) (strrchr(file, '/') ? strrchr(file, '/') + 1 : file)
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: `main.cpp` shows you are using C++, not C. Tag such question C++, not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ***only*** concatenate the **string literals** this way.

Example:

```
printf("%s", "{" "hello" " " "world" "\n");
```

The concatenation can only happen at the **compile time**.

You can't use anything but the ***string literals*** this way.

Your macro expands to:

```
    printf("%s\n", "[" (strrchr("/app/example.c", '/') ? strrchr("/app/example.c", '/') + 1 : "/app/example.c") "]");
```

and it does not meet this criteria.

As a general remark - avoid macros and use only if you really understand what you are doing. Macros can be very dangerous.

Simple example:

```
#define INC(x) ((x)++)

int foo(int y)
{
    return INC(y++);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strrchr` etc are executed in run-time. String literal concatenation such as `"[" MYFILENAME "]"` happens at compile-time. You cannot wildly mix the two.

It is strongly recommended to carry out all of this in run-time using a *function* instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot concatenate macros in this way:

```
#define __MYFILE__ "[" MYFILENAME "]"
```

Why don't you just

```
 printf("[%s]\n", MYFILENAME);
```

By the way, remember that folder separator '/' is for unix and '\' for windows.

Comment: I need to use this as a tag in a logger macro