How to dynamically expand a variable in CPP
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const string getFileNameAsVarName(string filename, int lineNo)
{
  string s = "";
  for (char c : filename)
  {
    if (c > 'a' && c < 'z')
    {
      s += c;
    }
  }
  return s + to_string(lineNo);
}
#define DYNAMIC_NAME() (getFileNameAsVarName(__FILE__, __LINE__))
#define NAME() aaa

int main()
{
  int NAME() = 123; // OK Expands to: aaa
  int DYNAMIC_NAME() = 234; //Not OK Expands to: 
  // (getFileNameAsVarName("/Users/guichizhao/Documents/GitHub/learn/main.cpp", 29))
  return 0;
}

It may look wired, but we have a valid use case. Our intention is to declare a dynamically named variable i.e. The variable name is determined by the filename and lineNo, We try to achieve this by using a macro, it seems the only chance we get to achieve our goal.
The problem is that a file name is not a legal cpp variable name, If we make it legal using cpp code, the MACRO complains, after the MACRO substitution, it is not valid anymore, see the comment in the code
So, is there any way to solve the dilemma, or is there another way to get a dynamically named variable?
In addition, we use CMake in our project, not sure if CMAKE can help, any solutions related to CMAKE are also highly appreciated

Could we see the use case?  How would you ever refer back to the variable?

declare a dynamically named variable Not possible. If you want to dynamically define variable names, consider python or bash, a scripting langauge. What you usually do, is concatenate a static name with line number, like XCONCAT(aaa, __LINE__).

Overall, this feels like XY question. What is the point of defining a variable like that, if you'll never get the chance to refer to it? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Re: if (c > 'a' && c < 'z') -- this is not guaranteed to work. Use std::islower or, to include both lowercase and uppercase letters, std::isalpha.

@NathanOliver I asked the question on behalf of my coworker, I will call you back later. It seems such trick is used by a open source project.  He follows.  Any other way to achieve the same goal is definitely appreciated

@PeteBecker I dose not matter though... just a demo. The point is how to use macro properly

If you want to dynamically add a name that is associated with a variable you may want a std::map<std::string,sometype> or std::hash_map<std::string,sometype> where the string is the name.

@KamilCuk I will come reach you later after I ask my co-worker, It seem like ralted to some dynamic function pointer. I will point to the open source repo by then

@drescherjm This is also what I believe. I will point you out a open source repo after I reach my co-worker tomorrow

When compiling, use -DFILE_TOKEN=main_cpp and then use the FILE_TOKEN for the file name to be concatenated with the line number.

"we have a valid use case" That's not enough information to ask us how to satisfy your use case.  Please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than asking us to fix your solution to a mysterious problem.

Why do you want to do this? ("Our intention is to declare a dynamically named variable" is not a valid use case, that's your proposed solution to whatever the actual use case is.) Why does the name of the variable matter? The name doesn't exist at runtime anyway.

You can't, fundamentally.
Macros are handled by the C++ preprocessor. It works on tokens. It can turn a token into a string (FOO => "FOO") but it can't turn a string back into a token. __FILE__ is a string, as you discovered, while a variable name has to be an unquoted token.
getFileNameAsVarName is a C++ function, and even consteval functions run after the preprocessor has completely finished. At that time, all tokens are final.


When compiling, use -DFILE_TOKEN=main_cpp and then use FILE_TOKEN for the file name to be concatenated with the line number.

–
Eljay (link)

And the filename above can be generated automatically by a command shell. Much of this is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path
